# Is there a way to solve this "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.products.map')"?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, fetch

My React App pulls data from a Djano REST API through the **api.js** file below.

**api.js**

```
const URLS = {

  PRODUCTS: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/",
  PRODUCT: (id) => `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/${id}`,

};

const wrappedFetch = (...args) => {
  return fetch(...args).then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  });
};

const get = (url) => wrappedFetch(url);


// PRODUCT API
const loadProducts = () => get(URLS.PRODUCTS);
const loadProduct = (id) => get(URLS.PRODUCT(id));

export {

  loadProducts,
  loadProduct,

};
```

The data does not successfully render at its first load and identifies an issue in my **useAllProducts.js** file below.

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { loadProducts } from "./api/api";

function useAllProducts() {
  const { data = [] } = useQuery("products", loadProducts);
  console.log(data)
 
  return data.products.map(({ id }) => id);
}

export default useAllProducts;
```

The error is `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.products.map')`

At **useAllProduts.js**
Once I change `return data.products.map(({ id }) => id);` to  `return data.map(({ id }) => id);` and back again to `return data.products.map(({ id }) => id);`, the products render successfully.

Replacing the above with

`return data.products && products.map(({ id }) => id);`

does not solve the error.

Also when I refresh the page, the same error persists (`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.products.map'`). I think my App renders data before it's populated and possibly needs to add a condition or async/await in my **api.js**.

How do I solve this: I have tried adding async/await, but I feel I blundered and therefore did not work.

I know there are similar questions, but my **api.js** file is quite different.

Please help me.

Comment: I faced the same issue, my Ui rendering before the data fetched from the backend. The workaround I used was return data.products!==undefined && products.map(({ id }) => id); Try this and let me know if it works

Comment: @VasanthSelvaraj Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that returns an error as shown: `src/data/useAllProducts.js
  Line 8:39:  'products' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: What exactly is `data` supposed to be? In the declaration you've assigned an empty array as a fallback value, but then later access a `products` property which will be undefined.

Comment: @DrewReese Data returned includes Objects(which are pages), and products(As an array). I am getting the products in a data array with recursive, hence, I have to include data.products, which works but returns an error when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return data.products && products.map(({ id }) => id);` is incorrect because `products` is undefined in `products.map`. You'd want to do something more like `return data.products && data.products.map(({ id }) => id);`.

On the initial render when data has yet to be fetched (***and cached***) `data.products` is undefined. When you change the code to `data.map(({ id }) => id);` and back and it works, it's likely that the hook is able to read the cached response and `data.products` is defined.

If you are expecting the fetched data to have a `products` property that is the array, then you can provide a better fallback value, and use a null-check on the potentially undefined property accesses.

Examples:

```
function useAllProducts() {
  const { data = { products: [] } } = useQuery("products", loadProducts);
 
  return (data.products ?? []).map(({ id }) => id);
}
```

```
function useAllProducts() {
  const { data } = useQuery("products", loadProducts);
 
  return (data?.products ?? []).map(({ id }) => id);
}
```

Comment: You're a genius! My app now works as expected. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { loadProducts } from "./api/api";

function useAllProducts() {
  const { data = [] } = useQuery("products", loadProducts);
  console.log(data)
 
  return data.products ? data.products.map(({ id }) => id) :[];
}

export default useAllProducts;
```